# AWS - Application Load Balancer - 502 Badgateway - Node JS application

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have an node js application with express library running in ECS (docker image). When we tried to access the target instances from load balancer, we are getting 502 Badgateway in 60 seconds.

Idle timeout configuration in ALB : 1205 seconds

On checking access logs of ALB, we understood that response_processing_time is -1 and we dont see any issues in application logs.

How can change this configuration (KeepAlive) of 60 seconds in target instance. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: How is your target group setup up? Port and protocol (http, https) to connect to your instances?

Comment: Target group is pointing to 2 ECS Task IPs. These ips are registered in target groups. We are uploading file, when we upload small file, the process gets succeeded but when upload large file over 200 MB then we are getting 502 Bad gateway. On inspecting the access logs from load balancer, we understand that  response_processing_time is -1. for larger files timeout occurs at 60 seconds. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/access-log-collection.html#access-log-entry-format.   But ECs tasks are always healthy and good

Comment: 60 seconds is exact default value of [connection idle timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout). Maybe increasing it could help?